# DNS - Unbound - How to provide different IP for a server based on client network

Tags: domain-name-system, unbound, split-dns

We have an intranet DNS server using Unbound in FreeBSD. We have another file server with multiple network IP, First one is `10.10.10.10` and Second one in  `192.168.10.10`.

Is there any way that DNS server provide different IP for this file server based on the client network?

Eg:
For the user from 10.10.x.x network, fileserver ip should be `10.10.10.10`
For the user from 192.168.x.x network, fileserver ip should be `192.168.10.10`.

Comment: I'am not a BSD expert, but I know in enterprise grade firewall you can do a reverse NAT policy to solve that problem. That make that if a request for the bad IP come inside the LAN, it rewrite the destination to the correct IP. Like if in 10.10.10.* and it request 192.168.10.10, the router correct to 10.10.10.10 the conversation

Comment: The jargon term for that is usually "split horizon" -  See this answer: https://serverfault.com/a/1058218/960939 using the `access-control-view` feature and the docs here: https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/topics/filtering/tags-views.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to provide different IP for a server based on client network

The jargon for that is normally "[split horizon DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-horizon_DNS)".

In Unbound that is implemented via "[tags and views](https://unbound.docs.nlnetlabs.nl/en/latest/topics/filtering/tags-views.html)" functionality. Those make it possible to send specific DNS answers based on the IP address of the client.

> The tags functionality makes it possible to divide client source addresses in categories (tags), and use local-zone and local-data information for these specific tags.

> A view is a named list of configuration options. The supported view configuration options are local-zone and local-data.

> A view is configured using a view clause. There may be multiple view
> clauses, each with a unique name. For example:
>
> ```
> view:
>     name: "firstview"
>     local-zone: example.com inform
>     local-data: 'example.com TXT "this is an example"'
>     local-zone: refused.example.nl refuse
> ```
>
> ...
>
> Mapping a view to a client can be done using the access-control-view
> element:
>
> ```
>  access-control-view: 10.0.5.0/24 firstview
> ```